# Possible for MySQL to autodelete rows where DATETIME is older than _?

Tags: mysql, datetime

My table has a column called date_time where simple DATETIME values are stored. Is it possible to configure a MySQL table/database to automatically delete rows where the DATETIME value is a passed date (let's say, 3 days old)? Or is it necessary to use PHP scripts/queries to pass along the requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, mySQL has no provision for this.

You might be able to set up a stored procedure and a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) but honestly, I think it's much easier to either set up a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call a PHP script, or send a "delete everything older than x days" query from PHP whenever, for example, a user logs in or something.

That's what I would do.